# Is the boundary of $ Q=\bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\{t\}\times S(t) $ empty when $S(t)$ is a boundaryless hypersurface?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

For each $t$, let $S(t)$ be a compact hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\partial S(t) = \emptyset$.

Consider 
$$ Q=\bigcup_{t \in (0,T)}\{t\}\times S(t) $$

Is the boundary of $Q$ empty? I don't think it is.. consider a growing (in time) circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, its spacetime diagram is like a cone/cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and this cylinder appears to me to have  aboundary.

I ask because if the boundary is not empty then I would get boundary terms in integrals over $Q$. However, we can write
$$\int_Q f = \int_0^T \int_{S(t)}f$$ and integrate in parts in space without getting a boundary term (since $S(t)$ has no boundary).. This is a bit confusing?

Comment: Are you using the topological definition of "boundary", or are you using it in the sense of "manifold with boundary"?  If the latter, the fact that you're taking the *open* interval $(0,T)$ is significant (the cylinder in question has no boundary since it doesn't include the bounding circle).

Comment: Hmm, I think I mean the sense of "manifold with boundary" (for example, I would consider a sphere to have no boundary, but a sphere cut in half would have a boundary on the chopped part). 

I see. I was under the impression including end points made no difference to being in the boundary or not..

Comment: Using the "manifold with boundary" definition, the boundary must be part of the set.  So an open disc is a manifold without boundary, and a closed disc is a manifold with boundary.  Often discussions will restrict to compact or complete manifolds, which eliminates the possibility of the open disc case.

Comment: Well, what i am concerned with is: if I integrate by parts over $Q$, will I get a boundary integral?